# Micronaut - Resolve place holders in properties file

Tags: micronaut

How to resolve placeholders in properties file similar to the below one.

I am using an external properties file - dev.properties with entries similar to below:

```
db.database: testdb
db.user: testuser
db.password: password
db.dev_server: server1
db.port: 9999
db.url: jdbc:database:${db.dev_server}:${db.port}/${db.database}
```

Loading this using -Dmicronaut.config.files=path_to_dev.properties

```
@ConfigurationProperties("db")
class Config {
    // all the properties (database, user etc) including getters and setters createted 

    public Config () {

    }
}
```

When I inject Config in another class, it is not able to resolve place holders in url property.

```
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not resolve placeholder ${db.dev_server} in value: jdbc:database:${db.server}:${db.port}/${db.database}
```

Comment: I figured out the answer in micronaut docs. Micronaut normalizes properties into kebab case so it will not be able to resolve ${dev_server}. Changing this to ${dev-server} works. Is there any other work around for this?

Comment: It's not a workaround. It is what you're supposed to do

Comment: is there a possibility to log which properties are existing .. cause sometimes its pretty hard to find out

Comment: Is your property file supposed to use `=` instead of `:`?

Answer (score 1):

It is the first thing developers hit once trying to migrate existing project, as not always properties are not following kebab case.
If you migrate a project or third party library it is often to hit this but behaviour is expected and documented.

Documentation is clear, it expects kebab case.
https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#_property_value_binding

In the end it is simply converting any snake case or camel case properties to kebab case.